# Compile with gcc on Macos 10.14.5 that will support earlier versions of Mac

Tags: macos, gcc

I have a c ++ code that I wrote that uses almost nothing, which is not the language itself (except using `osascript`).

After compiling it on my operating system version (10.14.5) with the following flags:
D_DEBUG, Os, Wall, Wextra

I found that it was not running on older operating systems (in 10.13 for example - it raises an error that it can only run on 10.14 or later)

What are the right flags to use to tell GCC, that I want to support as many MacOs versions as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a versioning flag: `-mmacosx-version-min=10.9`

And let the compiler know where the SDK is: `-isysroot= =/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk`

The older SDKs are available in older xcode bundles, or via https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases.  You need to decompress the SDK and place the folder inside the xcode bundle, as shown in the sysroot flag above.

Apple sayeth: You must target your compile for the oldest version of OS X on which you want to run the executable. In addition, you should install and use the cross-development SDK for that version of OS X. For more information, see [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i)